# указать тип значение с плавающей точкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Зделать значение val не int  а float

```
import pandas as pd

(pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Chechire Cat\Downloads\multiTimeline(1).csv', header=None, names=['dt','val'], parse_dates=['dt'], skiprows=3)
   [['val', 'dt']]
   .to_csv(r'C:\Users\Chechire Cat\PycharmProjects\mosia\primer1.csv', index=False, header=None, date_format='%d.%m.%Y'))
```

Либо же указать при построении графика int значение

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')


url = r'C:\Users\Chechire Cat\Downloads\multiTimeline.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url, names=['val', 'date'], index_col=[1], decimal=',',
             parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)

df.plot()
#plt.savefig('d:/temp/out.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: вопрос не ясен. Вы хотите в csv писать 123.0 вместо 123? Покажите пример ввода (пару строк csv) и соответствующий желаемый вывод¶ Причём здесь графики вообще не ясно. Какое это отношение к примеру с csv имеет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вашего вопроса не понятно что за графики вы хотите построить и какое это имеет отношение к типу столбца, поэтому я отвечу на первую часть вопроса (`"указать тип значения с плавающей точкой"`).

можно указать тип столбца при чтении из CSV:

```
In [4]: df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\temp\file.csv', header=None, names=['dt','val'], 
                         parse_dates=['dt'], dtype={'val':'float'})

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
          dt   val
0 2018-02-23  15.0
1 2018-02-24  32.0
2 2018-02-25  16.0
3 2018-02-26  70.0
4 2018-02-27  28.0
5 2018-02-28  14.0
6 2018-03-01  27.0
7 2018-03-02  29.0
8 2018-03-03  81.0

In [6]: df.dtypes
Out[6]:
dt     datetime64[ns]
val           float64
dtype: object
```

или конвертировать столбец DF после чтения из CSV:

```
In [7]: df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\temp\file.csv', header=None, names=['dt','val'], 
                         parse_dates=['dt'])

In [8]: df.dtypes
Out[8]:
dt     datetime64[ns]
val             int64     # <------ NOTE!
dtype: object

In [9]: df['val'] = df['val'].astype('float')

In [10]: df.dtypes
Out[10]:
dt     datetime64[ns]
val           float64     # <------ NOTE!
dtype: object
```